# Complex queries using redis and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, redis

I have a data on which i need to do search based on mutiple queries eg

```
list1=redisClient.zrangebyscore('FID', min=20150000, max=20190000)
```

the above code gives me all values for FID(First intriductory date ) which has date between 2015 jan to 2019 jan.So it gives me the desired result but i would also like to append this search the result set based on date and NTM value as 1 for all the dates between 205 jan to  2019 jan .

```
list2 =redisClient.zrangebyscore('NTM', min=1, max=1)
```

How can i  club both these search conditions together .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it with a single search is to find a clever way of encoding both values (FID and NTM) in a single score. If there isn't such a clever way, you'll need to perform both searches and then intersect the results yourself.

Tip: instead of doing the intersection in your application code, look into using Redis' Lua scripts to save on network bandwidth and latency.

Comment: I achieved it with the second approach you mentioned.thanks using sinter on zadd and sadd  data types.zadd  set had to converted back to sadd using redisClient.sadd('a', *set(list1)) and then i was able to do intersection on both sets to find commn data